# Create Shiny DataTable based on selected input

Tags: sql, r, shiny

The following code (within my shiny app) is giving me this error:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  dataTable <- reactive ({
    data <- input$dataset
    con <- 
      dbConnect(
        drv = dbDriver("MySQL"), 
        dbname = "Database",
        host = 'remote',
        port = 3306,
        user = "user",
        password = "password") 
    on.exit(dbDisconnect(con)) 
    dbGetQuery(con, paste("select * from ", data, ";"))
  })

  output$myTable <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(dataTable(), 
              rownames = FALSE, 
              filter = "top",
              extensions = 'Buttons', 
              options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = I('colvis')))
  })

})
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Data Search"), 

  # SidePanel -------------------------------------------
  # -The Input/Dropdown Menu that Control the Output
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput(
        inputId = "dataset", 
        label = "Select Dataset", 
        choices = c("", "Schools", "GradRates"), 
        selected = "",
        multiple = FALSE),


      width = 3

    ),


    # MainPanel -------------------------------------------
    # -The Output/Table Displayed Based on Input
    mainPanel(
        dataTableOutput(outputId = "myTable"), 
        width = 9
      )
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have most likely problem with this line

```
 dbGetQuery(con, paste("select * from ", data, ";"))
```

It appears that variable data doesn't contain table name as expected. Check your code where you are inserting table name into data.

Comment: ok so i changed the code to :      while (is.null(input$dataset) && 
    is.null(input$year)){
            data <- "select * from Schools;"
          }
          if (!is.null(input$dataset) && !is.null(input$year)) {
            data <- paste("Select * from Schools natural join", input$dataset, 
    "where", input$dataset, ".year =", input$year, ";")
          }
          dbGetQuery(con, data)

Comment: i dont know why i cant edit that to make it look nicer but basically, it says while both of the input fields are null, the query is a simple select, but when theyre both filled, then input the given fields in the appropriate parts of the query

Comment: Formatting capabilities of comments are very limited, so if you want to add any formatted output, then best way is to add it to your original question. Your edit seems reasonable and will work most of the time. What behavior you want when only one of input parameters is null? Now you will skip it. I would prefer to do query if both are OK otherwise run simple query. And one more thing if the data you are using are input from users, then you have created problem called SQL INJECTION.  Hmm, R doesn't support prepared statements. So you have to be really careful what data you allow to reach DB.